# Count Clicks and Sort Tags by the clicks Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, tags

I have a list of tags, this list is populated by a database and MVC.
I have a razor code that pulls in each tag for sorting purposes. 
Recently I was asked to have each tag track how many times it's clicked, and then reorder the tags displayed by how many times the tags have been clicked.

Here is my razor code for the list of tags

```
<ul class="pills" id="tags">
    @foreach (var tag in tags)
         {
             <li><a href="#" data-tag-selector="@tag">@tag</a></li>
         }
</ul>
```

I tried 
var clicks = 0 and adding onclick=clicks++ to the a href
but I think I might be on the wrong track. I think Javascript might be my go to.

Comment: You'll need some place on the back-end to store the number of clicks for each tag. Whatever you store using a JS clicks=0 variable is only good for that user during that page view. So how do you plan to store the clicks value and associate it with the tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that will work until you refresh the browser:

### HTML partial:

```
<ul class="pills" id="tags">
    <li data-click-count=0>tag1</li>
    <li data-click-count=0>tag2</li>
    <li data-click-count=0>tag3</li>
</ul>
```

### jQuery snippet

When a tag is clicked, increment that tag's click count and then re-sort the tag list.

```
var $tags = $('#tags').find('li');

$tags.click(function (e) {
  // Get the click count for the tag that was just clicked
  var tagCount = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-click-count');

  $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-click-count', parseInt(tagCount) + 1);

  // Remove tags from the DOM but keep data so you can reorder them
  $tags.detach();

  // Sort the tags by click count
    $tags.sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(b).attr('data-click-count') - $(a).attr('data-click-count');
  });

  // Insert them back into the unordered list DOM element
  $('#tags').html($tags);

});
```

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/adamgibbons/ohos5a17/

Comment: This is perfect! I am sure I can use a cookie to retain the information.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this fiddle will help. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabs00/tp7pxhga/)

I track clicks by adding an an attribute to each tag element. So every time that element is clicked, it increments the data-clicked attribute. Also, when it is clicked, I resort the tags then readd them to the dom in the correct order.

note this uses jquery

```js
    $(function(){
      var $taglist = $('#tags');

      var tags = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        tags.push($('<li class="tag" data-clicked="0">' + i + '</li>'));
        $taglist.append(tags[i]);
      }

      var $tags = $('.tag');

      $tags.on('click', onClick);

      function onClick(e){
        $(this).attr('data-clicked', incrementer($(this)));
        tags = sort(tags);

        $taglist.html('');

        tags.forEach(function($tag){
          $taglist.append($tag);
        });

        $tags.on('click', onClick);
      }
    });

    function incrementer($elem){
      return parseInt($elem.attr('data-clicked')) + 1;
    }

    function sort(tags){
      return tags.sort(function($a, $b){
        return $b.attr('data-clicked') - $a.attr('data-clicked');
      })
    }
```

```css
#tags li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #f4e4e4;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
      <ul id="tags">
      </ul>
    </div>
```